# how to give different access authority to different users credential in magento

Tags: magento

I have client requirement that he want to me to make different prices list of products for different users, for example there will be two types of users one normal users and other one are doctors , so he want that if normal users come to this website then the price list should be different as for doctors, like for doctor a particular product rate can be 50 Rs but the same product for normal user is 70 Rs .

so i want to know can this be possible in magento and if "yes".
 How to do it??????.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to accomplish this using either

1. Customer Group
2. Multi Website
3. Third Party extension

Take a look @

- [Different prices for different groups? (wholesale prices, etc.)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/23057/)
- [Magento: How to Setup Simple Customer Specific Discount Pricing](http://www.beperpetual.com/2009/04/how-to-setup-customer-pricing-in.html)